# Weird Objective-C BOOL behavior

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I'm having a rather confusing problem.  When I create a local BOOL variable, it ignores the value I'm assigning to it.

For example:

`BOOL myBoolean = NO;`

This line of code, according to the debugger, results in `myBoolean` equaling `YES`, as shown below:
[image: debugger screenshot]
(the warning symbol is about the variable being unused.)

Why is this, and what can I do about it?

I've tried setting it to `NO` later on in my code, but it remains at `YES`.

I've tried initializing it without a value, and even if I set it to `NO` afterward, it's still stuck as `YES`.  Even initializing it with `YES` and then trying to set it to `NO` leaves it as `YES`.

I'm at a complete loss here… any help and/or explanation would very much be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works for me...that sounds very weird.

Comment: redefined in different scopes?

Comment: I’d suspect the debugger more than a Boolean value not working. What happens if you log its value? `NSLog(@"value: %i", myBoolean);` should output a 1 if it’s YES and a 0 otherwise.

Comment: Not certain, but the compiler may be allowed to skip the store if the variable is unused. Insert another dummy statement between those two, and break after it; also try inserting some usage of the variable.

Comment: If it's not the debugger then you're probably accidentally building with compiler optimisation enabled, and it's declining to store anything to `myBoolean` given that it doesn't need to in order to produce correct behaviour from the code presented.

Comment: Thanks Noah, I've added an answer based on my findings from your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer:

It seems that the debugger doesn't properly display the values of BOOLs.  If I print the variable, as Noah suggested in the comments above, it indeed contains a `0`.

How weird… I wonder why this happens, and why Apple hasn't fixed it if it is indeed a bug, rather than intended behavior.  (I can't imagine why this would be intended, though.)

Comment: Can you confirm which optimization level you are using to do your debug build? Go to the target -> Build Settings -> Optimization Level (under Apple LLVM - Code Generation). It is possible, as mentioned on a different answer, that the compiler is optimizing the code and the debugger is not reading it right.

Comment: I'm running it as Debug, and my Optimzation Level is set to None [-O0] for Debug: http://imgur.com/a/vNiql
Link-Time Optimization is also off.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't use the `myBoolean` variable, the compiler is allowed to optimize it out.  The debugger might display an incorrect value in that case (because the variable isn't actually stored anywhere), although usually it just doesn't show the variable if it's not accessible.

Comment: This is what I figured too, but is this true even with Xcode's default Debug settings? I.e., -O0?

Comment: This same issue happens in a more complex instance, where the variable is indeed used and has its value modified several times.  In order to test it better, I moved the problematic code to a blank project's AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.